# How to execute Linux shell script with inittab file

Tags: linux, bash

I created a shell script with the following content.

```
#!/bin/bash
TMP_FILE=/tmp/inet_up
no_inet_action(){
    reboot
}
HOUR="$(date +'%H')"
if [ $HOUR -le 22 -a $HOUR -ge 9 ]; then
  if ping -c5 192.168.7.100; then
    echo "Internet OK">$TMP_FILE
  else
    echo "No Internet">$TMP_FILE
    no_inet_action
  fi
fi
```

It will ping an IP address during 09:00 to 22:00 and if there is no internet connection, it will write a line to a file and reboot the device. I put the following line in inittab and expect that it will run every 5 minutes interval. I don't see the file in `/tmp` folder. The script is executable. What is the right way to execute it? I saw some blog suggest to put it under `/etc/init.d`; which is right way?

`inittab` is located in `/etc/` folder.

```
    ::respawn:/sbin/delayexec 600 /etc/check_inet.sh
```

Comment: This depends on your distribution.  You describe a classic method, but these days many distros eschew the classic `init` behavior.  Those that rely on `systemd`, for example, ignore `/etc/inittab` altogether.

Comment: I check my system is Linux 3.6.9+ armv5tejl.

Comment: You should probably be using `cron` for this (`cron` is a utility for executing scripts on a schedule).

Comment: @RotatingWheel, that tells us the kernel, but the init system isn't part of the kernel; we need to know what the distro is.

Comment: @RotatingWheel, ...*ideally*, your distro will have a real process supervision system -- systemd was mentioned above; there are also runit, upstart, DJB daemontools, launchd, and many others. Whichever one your OS vendor supports in the right one to use. (If you're building your own distro, ie. on an embedded system, I strongly recommend [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/) or, even better, [s6](https://skarnet.org/software/s6/) -- both of which are built to be very small and simple).

Comment: BTW, https://skarnet.org/software/s6/why.html -- while being principally an advocacy document for s6 -- also incidentally discusses much of what a process supervision system should do and why, so while obviously being quite biased it's a good introduction to the field.

Comment: (All the above being said -- I *do* agree that `cron` is the right tool for this particular case).

Comment: According to this page (http://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job) if I try crontab -e  I get "crontab: can't change directory to '/var/spool/cron/crontabs': No such file or directory" in terminal

Comment: My stuff works as I thought experts mislead me

Answer (score 1):

After searching around and trying several hours, found the solution.
If I put following content in inittab file it works just fine for me. So I don't need to use crontab as mentioned by experts in the comment(I am not Linux expert and no time to investigate detail, just need to make working my tasks). Hope this may be helpful to some other, partial content of inittab.

```
::respawn:/sbin/delayexec 300 /bin/sh /etc/check_inet.sh
```

Here is the final code that I am using after removing the echo command:

```
#!/bin/bash
no_inet_action(){
reboot
}
HOUR="$(date +'%H')"
if [ $HOUR -le 22 -a $HOUR -ge 9 ]; then
if ping -c5 192.168.7.100; then
else
no_inet_action
fi
fi
```